# QT 5.2 - No 'Qt Gui application' option

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I'm using qt tutorial from => http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/gettingstartedqt.html
but I got a problem because I can't choose in QT Creator 'Qt Gui application' option.

I have already read that is due the library isn't installed but I've done it.

Comment: Have you tried the option _Qt Widgets Application_ ? It's the same as the _Qt Gui Application_ in this new version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a stupid question from me. :)

Comment: @user1611534: does that mean you solved your issue? If yes, what was the solution?

Comment: 'Qt Widgets Application' is the same as 'Qt Gui application'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to create either a `QtQuick` based application or `QtWidgets`. See the screenshot below what I have about it.

[image]